# Como importar XML de Dicionário de Dados para SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, xml, dicionário

Para contextualizar, estou fazendo um dicionário de dados para um banco de dados local, para isso utilizei uma ferramenta chamada "DataBase NoteTaker".

Essa ferramenta carrega os dados do banco de dados e permite que eu faça comentários sobre os dados das tabelas e salva as alterações em arquivo XML. Arquivo mto extenso para por no texto, esta disponivel [Aqui.](https://www.dropbox.com/s/clpnkcbhf66du8o/teste.xml?dl=0)

Primeiramente preciso saber se tem como importar esses tipos de dados para o SQL Server. Se tiver, como realizo essa importação?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sim, é possível, faça o seguinte:

```
CREATE TABLE XMLwithOpenXML
(
Id INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
XMLData XML,
LoadedDateTime DATETIME
)


INSERT INTO XMLwithOpenXML(XMLData, LoadedDateTime)
SELECT CONVERT(XML, BulkColumn) AS BulkColumn, GETDATE() 
FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'c:\seuarquivo.xml', SINGLE_BLOB) AS x;


SELECT * FROM XMLwithOpenXML
```

Feito isso, você criará uma tabela para armazenar o conteúdo do seu XML. 
Agora para ler esse conteúdo fiz um teste com o seu arquivo:

```
DECLARE @XML AS XML, @hDoc AS INT, @SQL NVARCHAR (MAX)

SELECT @XML = XMLData FROM XMLwithOpenXML

EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @hDoc OUTPUT, @XML

select @xml
SELECT [Key], [Value]
FROM OPENXML(@hDoc, 'DatabaseNoteTakerProject/Project/Setting')
WITH 
(
[key] [varchar](50) '@key',
[value] [varchar](100) '@value'
)

EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @hDoc
GO
```

Obtive como resultado: (que fazem parte do seu XML)

> saveConnectionSettingsSeparately  False
>
> saveOneFilePerObject  False
>
> saveObjectHistory True
>
> publishPath
>
> publishXSLPath
>
> includeFilter NULL
>
> excludeFilter NULL

Mais informações e detalhes pode encontrar aqui:

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2899/importing-and-processing-data-from-xml-files-into-sql-server-tables/

Comment: Deu certo, tive um pouco de dificuldade pra entender o retorno do resultado. O que eu queria era o retorno dos comentários msm, tive que fazer alterações no caminho e nas chaves.
Muito obrigado

Comment: maravilha... realmente voce tem que ir na "unha" e fazer um a um pq o xml nao é padrao.. msa depois que fizer o primeiro boa! abs

Comment: A critério de conhecimentos, quem quiser, na busca de outras informações, achei uma ferramenta que faz esse dicionário dentro do próprio SQL Server, não tendo a necessidade de importar o XML, só que ela é paga: [link] (https://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-compare/)